# how to create virtual host in apache with main apache server working?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have created a virtual host entry (zf2app.loc) for a website running on localhost, but now all my request are being handled by this virtual host.

Even if i access localhost it shows me the content from zf2app.loc document root.
My main apache server is not working now but i want it to work as it was working before creating virtual host entry.

Answer (score 1):

You will need two virtualhost settings, keep the origin one (for localhost), and add another one to `zf2app.loc`.

For example, in Ubuntu's apache2, the origin one is in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` (and link to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then add your `zf2app.loc` into `/etc/apache2/sites-available/zf2app.loc.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName zf2app.loc
        DocumentRoot /var/www/zf2app.loc/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/zf2app.loc-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/zf2app.loc-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then link this file to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/zf2app.loc.conf` too.

Comment: can u plz tell solution for xampp